# How to use 指 when giving a definition?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

How is 指 used, what is it's role in definitions such as this (from Wikipedia):

> 研究生是**指**获得学士学位后继续深造.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, 指 (zhi3) means "refers to". Sometimes it is interchangeable with 表示 (biao3shi4) or 表达 (biao3da2), which mean "expresses". Just like in an English dictionary, you might see a word with a definition that says X refers to Y or X is used to express Y. These words are used in a basically parallel way.

Comment: so 是指 together means "refers to"?

Comment: Maybe "is referring to" would be close in English with all of our weird tenses. I think this 是 is not essential to the sentence, but adds emphasis.

Comment: @trideceth12 You are right. "是指" is used together, meaning "refers to". "是" *is* an essential part. (native speaker here)